# Webpack change all url() paths to same path

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, stylus

I have a webpack config that processes many .styl (Stylus) files and within those stylesheets I have many url('..path/to/asset.svg') that I'd like to change to output as url('images/asset.svg') regardless of the intial path specified.

Is this possible with webpack or webpack plugin, I've had a look but I can't find anything that fits the bill.

Here is my current config (relevant section):

```
     module : {
       loaders : [{
         test : /\.styl?/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         include: STYLE_DIR,
         use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
         fallback: 'style-loader',
         use: ['css-loader','stylus-loader']
   })
  }
```

Your input is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't take care of itself no matter what the path, you could add aliases for the paths you want to switch through css-loader: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#alias

```
use: [
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        alias: {
          "../path/to/asset": "images",
          "other/path/place": "images"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      loader: "stylus-loader"
    }
]
```